# Cant fromat String to Date

Tags: javascript, date, type-conversion, format

When I try to convert a string value to a Date I get the error message "Invalid date"

```
timestamp : string = "2017:03:22 08:45:22";
.
.
let time = new Date(timestamp);
console.log("Time: ",time); //here I get   Time: Invalid date
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Comment: It's not a valid timestamp. Valid date strings must be conform to ISO8601.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your string must be in ISO date format you can change it like in the code below:

```js
let timestamp : string = "2017:03:22 08:45:22";

let timestampISO : string = timestamp.replace(':','-').replace(':','-').replace(' ','T');

let time = new Date(timestampISO);

console.log("Time: ",time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date must be a version of an ISO format.

To be more specific, it must be a version of ISO8601. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Example:

```
let time = new Date("2017/03/22 08:45:22");
```