# Date from numeric to sring PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone have a better way of the below? Basically I want to echo the date in 11 Aug 2019 format after the user had entered in DD MM YYYY format.

```
  $dateD = "14";
  $dateM = "02";
  $dateY = "2019";

  echo $dateD, (" ");

  if ($dateM === "01") {
    echo "Jan";
  } else if ($dateM === "02") {
    echo "Feb";
  } else if ($dateM === "03") {
    echo "Mar";
  } else if ($dateM === "04") {
    echo "Apr";
  } else if ($dateM === "05") {
    echo "May";
  } else if ($dateM === "06") {
    echo "Jun";
  } else if ($dateM === "07") {
    echo "Jul";
  } else if ($dateM === "08") {
    echo "Aug";
  } else if ($dateM === "09") {
    echo "Sep";
  } else if ($dateM === "10") {
    echo "Oct";
  } else if ($dateM === "11") {
    echo "Nov";
  } else if ($dateM === "12") {
    echo "Dec";
  }

  echo (" "), $dateY;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant fromat String to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947680/cant-fromat-string-to-date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` to parse a time string, and use `date()` to format it.

```
echo date('d M Y', strtotime("$dateY-$dateM-$dateD"));
```